# Tensorboard is not running in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, tensorflow, tensorboard

After launching tensorboard using:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir=/home/kv/data2/debug/Summaries/train/ --host 127.0.0.1 --port 6666
```

I get:

> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> Failed to connect to server 127.0.0.1

In Google Chrome (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, tensorflow 0.11.0).

I use proxy settings in my laptop and they are configured correctly.

But tensorboard opens in firefox but I get a blank image under events section.

How can I get this running in Google Chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured Chrome to not use your proxy for 127.0.0.1? Possibly by using `--proxy-bypass-list`?